# Conversion from date format in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, datetime, date-format

I have got date in YYYYMMDD format in Varchar. Got to change this to yyyy-mm-dd format and should add 1 to the date. Should convert back to YYYYMMDD format.

Can somebody help to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) first. Use CONVERT because you need to tell the convert function what the format is of your dataetime varchar. Further down the article I linked to you see the different acceptable formats. Looking down that table you learn that the format YYYYMMDD is called *ISO format* and the third parameter of our CONVERT has therefore to be 112.

and then use the [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) and CONVERT back again

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(d, 1,CONVERT(DATETIME, '20140121', 112) ),112)
```

For 2008 and up you can use the datatype DATE, in sqlserver 2005 only the types DATETIME and SMALLDATETIME exist.

working [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/28748/0)

Comment: backported to sql server 2005